# Using class attributes/methods across different threads - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, object, attributeerror, nonetype

I'll do my best to explain this issue in a clear way, it's come up as part of a much larger piece of software I'm developing for an A level project - a project that aims to create a simple version of a graphical programming system (think scratch made by monkeys with about 7 commands).

My trouble currently stems from the need to have an execution function running on a unique thread that is capable of interacting with a user interface that shows the results of executing the code blocks made by the user (written using the Tkinter libraries) on the main thread. This function is designed to go through a dynamic list that contains information on the user's "code" in a form that can be looped through and dealt with "line by line".

The issue occurs when the execution begins, and the threaded function attempts to call a function that is part of the user interface class. I have limited understanding of multi threading, so it's all too likely that I am breaking some important rules and doing things in ways that don't make sense, and help here would be great.

I have achieved close to the functionality I am after previously, but always with some errors coming up in different ways (mostly due to my original attempts opening a tkinter window in a second thread... a bad idea).

As far as I'm aware my current code works in terms of opening a second thread, opening the UI in the main thread, and beginning to run the execution function in the second thread. In order to explain this issue, I have created a small piece of code that works on the same basis, and produces the same "none type" error, I would use the original code, but it's bulky, and a lot more annoying to follow than below:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

#Represents what would be my main code
class MainClass():
    #attributes for instances of each of the other classes
    outputUI = None
    threadingObject = None

    #attempt to open second thread and the output ui 
    def beginExecute(self):
        self.threadingObject = ThreadingClass()
        self.outputUI = OutputUI()

    #called by function of the threaded class, attempts to refer to instance
    #of "outputUI" created in the "begin execute" function
    def execute(self):
        return self.outputUI.functionThatReturns()

#class for the output ui - just a blank box    
class OutputUI():

    #constructor to make a window
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.title = ("Window in main thread")
        root.mainloop()

    #function to return a string when called
    def functionThatReturns(self):
        return("I'm a real object, look I exist! Maybe")

#inherits from threading library, contains threading... (this is where my 
#understanding gets more patchy) 
class ThreadingClass(threading.Thread):

    #constructor - create new thread, run the thread...     
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    #auto called by self.start() ^ (as far as I'm aware)
    def run(self):
        #attempt to run the main classes "execute" function
        print(mainClass.execute())

#create instance of the main class, then attempt execution of some
#threading    
mainClass = MainClass()
mainClass.beginExecute()
```

When this code is run, it produces the following result:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "H:/Programs/Python/more more threading tests.py", line 33, in run
    print(mainClass.execute())
  File "H:/Programs/Python/more more threading tests.py", line 14, in execute
    return self.outputUI.functionThatReturns()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'functionThatReturns'
```

I guess it should be noted that the tkinter window opens as I hoped, and the threading class does what it's supposed to, but does not appear to be aware of the existence of the output UI. I assume this is due to some part of object orientation and threading of which I am woefully under-informed.

So, is there a way in which I can call the function in the output ui from the threaded function? Or is there a work around to something similar? 
It should be noted that I didn't put the creation of the output window in the **init** function of the main class, as I need to be able to create the output window and start threading etc as a result of another input.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, shout at me and I'll try and fix it, but help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is your order of operations. You create a `ThreadingClass` in `MainClass.beginExecute()`, which calls `self.start()`. That calls `run` which ultimately tries to call a function on `main.outputUI`. But `main.outputUI` hasn't been initialized yet (that's the *next* line in `beginExecute()`). You could probably make it work just by reordering those two lines. But you probably don't want to be calling `self.start()` in the thread's `__init__`. That seems like poor form.

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty much what I was worried about. Unfortunately I cannot fix the issue by reordering the commands, as that would call the UI's "mainloop()" on the main thread, preventing the second thread from being made.
However I took out the calls for the mainloop() and the start() functions from within where they had previously been called, and moved them beneath the creation of the objects. 
By, as you suggested, creating the UI object, then the threaded object, then starting the thread, and then running the UI's mainloop() I was able to fix the issue. 
Many thanks